# How to redirect to HTTPS with extended slash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I use this code in .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1 [R=301,L]     
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off      
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}$1
```

to redirect all request to https e.g **example.com** is redirected to **https://www.example.com** but my issue is that when the url is like this **example.com/hello** or **http://www.example.com/hello** it redirects but to **https** but it results in a 404 error, how do i redirect the URL even if it has example.com or example.com/hello to https://www.example.com or https://www.example.com/hello without 404 error.

Comment: When you directly enter `https://www.example.com/hello` in browser, does it work?

Comment: @anubhava it is an example URL nobody owns the domain it is for standard example cases

Comment: I understand it's an example. But whatever URL is giving you 404, is that working directly in browser (with https and www)